# docker install fails with unmet dependencies on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I'm trying to install docker on a debian wheezy (I want to run some nodejs apps on my server..). I've followed steps described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/) but when I execute

```
apt-get install docker-engine
```

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-engine : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: cgroupfs-mount but it is not installable or
                             cgroup-lite but it is not installable
                 Recommends: yubico-piv-tool (>= 1.1.0~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Being a total noob with docker and debian I don't really know whats causing this error.

below my kernel:

```
root@xxx:/home/xxx# uname -r
3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

**resolved**

This github issue [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16878) Helped me resolve this installation problem.

As mentionned by 'lidel' (13 Oct 2015) i have to use backport installs of init-system-helpers ...

i've just added the line below at the end of  */etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list*

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

and then

```
apt-get update && apt-get install init-system-helpers
apt-get install docker-engine
```

and now it works